# Javascript group objects by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

Firstly I need to group an array of object with respect to policy attribute's value. Then I need to group action and company fields. I tried to use lodash but could not get to the nested arrays.

From this =>

```
[
    {
        "action": "VIEW",
        "policy": "FORM"
    },
    {
        "action": "CREATE",
        "policy": "USER"
    },
    {
        "action": "VIEW",
        "policy": "USER"
    },
    {
        "company": "Microsoft",
        "policy": "FORM"
    },
    {
        "company": "Facebook",
        "policy": "USER"
    },
    {
        "company": "Twitter",
        "policy": "USER"
    }
]
```

to this =>

```
{
    "FORM": {
            "action": ["VIEW"],
            "company": ["Microsoft"]
        },
    "USER": {
            "action": ["CREATE", "VIEW"],
            "company": ["Facebook", "Twitter"]
        }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a simple [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop and some [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const data = [ { action: 'VIEW', policy: 'FORM', }, { action: 'CREATE', policy: 'USER', }, { action: 'VIEW', policy: 'USER', }, { company: 'Microsoft', policy: 'FORM', }, { company: 'Facebook', policy: 'USER', }, { company: 'Twitter', policy: 'USER', }, ];
let result = {};

for (const { action, policy, company } of data) {
  result[policy] = result[policy] ?? { action: [], company: [] };
  if (action) result[policy].action.push(action);
  if (company) result[policy].company.push(company);
}

console.log(result);
```

You could also do this using [`array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of a for loop:

```js
const data = [ { action: 'VIEW', policy: 'FORM' }, { action: 'CREATE', policy: 'USER' }, { action: 'VIEW', policy: 'USER' }, { company: 'Microsoft', policy: 'FORM' }, { company: 'Facebook', policy: 'USER' }, { company: 'Twitter', policy: 'USER' }, ];

const result = data.reduce((result, { action, company, policy }) => {
  result[policy] = result[policy] ?? { action: [], company: [] };
  action && result[policy].action.push(action);
  company && result[policy].company.push(company);
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

By this function, you can group by any field value .

```
const groupBy = (x, f) => x.reduce((a, b) => ((a[f(b)] ||= []).push(b), a), {})
```

For group by policy

```
groupBy(data, v => v.policy)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group by `policy` and separate the rest of the array and build nested groups.

```js
const
    data = [{ action: "VIEW", policy: "FORM" }, { action: "CREATE", policy: "USER" }, { action: "VIEW", policy: "USER" }, { company: "Microsoft", policy: "FORM" }, { company: "Facebook", policy: "USER" }, { company: "Twitter", policy: "USER" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { policy, ...o }) => {
        r[policy] ??= {};
        Object
            .entries(o)
            .forEach(([k, v]) => (r[policy][k] ??= []).push(v));
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash library for this solution :

```
const content = {
    "success": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "clustername": "c2",
            "monthday": "12/29"
        },
        {
            "clustername": "C3",
            "monthday": "12/29"
        },
        {
            "clustername": "C71",
            "monthday": "12/31"
        },
        {
            "clustername": "C34",
            "monthday": "12/31"
        },
        {
            "clustername": "C998",
            "monthday": "1/4"
        },
        {
            "clustername": "C99",
            "monthday": "1/4"
        }
    ]
};
function customName(n) {
  return {name:n.clustername};
}


const array =  _.chain(content.data)
    .groupBy("monthday")
    .map((value, key) => ({ name: key, children:  _.map(value,v => customName(v))
    }))
    .value()
console.log(array);
```